# Chrome console printing Text Twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-developers-console

I was using a Typescript and react tutorial to build a to-do list for which I had to create an InputField, and then type text into the box. When I tried to check my output using `console.log()` to check the output in the console. It shows the output twice. I tried re-writing the code, and also matched with the source code the tutorial gave but am unsure why even then I am facing the same issue. If anyone has seen something like this, please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! But sadly, we can't help you because you haven't posted any code. Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide your code so far so we can tell you what's wring with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This generally occurs due to React's lifecycle stages for components. If you add a `console.log` inside your render method then anything that would cause your component to re-render - which is complete normal from `prop` or `state` changes - will trigger the console log to occur.

You can make use of React's `useEffect` as follows to make sure your console log only logs when a specific value changes like this:

```
// call this inside your component
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(myInputValue);
}, [myInputValue]) // this dependency array listens for these prop/state value changes and runs the code in the block above whenever those values update.
```